# Aggregation after sorting and limit in Elastic Search 5.6

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have to do a aggregation on Elasticsearch documents after sorting the results and picking top n from it.
I tried to do this:

```json
{
   "size":1,
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "terms":{
                  "name.keyword":[
                     "some_name"
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "exists":{
                  "field":"3g_duration_count"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "sort":[
      {
         "tmst":{
            "order":"desc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "aggs":{
      "fieldNameAgg":{
         "avg":{
            "field":"3g_duration_count"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here the fetching of top n results is happening after aggregation (which makes no sense), I want to pick top n records based on the sort criteria and then apply aggregation. How do I achieve this?
I am using `Elasticsearch 5.6`.
Is there a way that I can assign the results of the inner query along with the sort and limit clauses to a child query and then apply the avg aggregator on top of that ? In that way I can ensure the limit is applied before the aggregation is happening .
An equivalent sql query might look like this :

```
select avg(field_value) from (select field_value from t1 order by tmst desc fetch first n rows ) t2
```

Is this something possible to accomplish in ElasticSearch 5.6 ?

Comment: What you see in hits is just the top N documents, but you have the guarantee that the aggregations have been computed on ALL documents matching the query. So what you see here is probably already what you expect

Comment: You may want to look at doing a `top_metrics` aggregation to sort the documents for your aggregation, and then do average aggregation as a sub-aggregation. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-metrics.html

Comment: Is there a way that I can put the sort and size inside the query object , so that aggregation works on only the subset which is picked by the size limit ?

Comment: @foobarbaz I think top_metrics is not available in 5.6 . I got this exception Unknown BaseAggregationBuilder [top_metrics]